# How to Edited: avoid collision between two trains that are going opposite direction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity

***I don't understand the concept.I'm not asking to do the math for me***

1. Suppose two trains with V1,V2 respectively .After a while ,both drivers see each other when they were X meters apart.Then they apply negative acceleration A1,A2 respectively .Prove they will avoid a collision when $V1^2  A2 + V2^2A1 = 2A1A2X $.

Now I tried two approaches

1. I assumed first train is standing still.Then the second train gets velocity=(V1+V2) and negative acceleration =(A1+A2) .Then I get this equation : (V1+V2)^2=2*(A1+A2)*X .
2. Then I tried the normal way of course . I assumed X=X1+X2 .then X1 =$V1^2/2A1$ and X2=$V2^2/2A2$.Then I can easily get to the answer .But what is wrong with my first approach?

EDIT : Math related to lift ,throwing object from balloon and even collision between two train that are going towards same direction can be done using my first approach .Or at least my answer matches with the book.Then why can I not do this for this math?
Proof: 1. I put values that satisfies my first attempt in a  simulator in OPHYSICS ,I tried to give the link where I put all the values but cen not generate that link.Sorry for that.But here are the values I used

```
V1=5 m/s
V2=-6 m/s
A1=-2 m/s^2
A2=4.05 m/s^2 
 X=10 m
```

For these values you will see both trains don't collide

2. Now If I put values in my second attempt I get

   V1 = 5 m/s
   V2 = -6 m/s
   A1 = -2 m/s^2
   A2 = 4.05 m/s^2

for this I get X=10.69 which doesn't match with simulation
Now you may think that my second attempt is at fault.But this question has come in  both my maths and physics textbooks and they show that the correct answer is  $V1^2  A2 + V2^2A1 = 2A1A2X $.
**Link to ophysics**:https://ophysics.com/k7.html then insert the given values to see for yourself

Comment: An accelerating/decelerating train is not an inertial reference frame (Newton's first law doesn't hold.)

Comment: @Vadim It's accelerations the op is dealing with right not forces? So inertial or non inertial shouldn't matter right?

Comment: If you're not doing this by paying careful attention to directions of vectors, you probably have a negative sign wrong somewhere. I'm not going to do that analysis for you, but this is a vector problem, so you better draw a picture and label everything clearly.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna the forces may not appear explicitly, but it doesn't change the fact that the OP is trying yo use the velocity transformations for the inertial reference frames, while this is not the case. Newton's first law defines the inertial reference frames, where the galilean transformations apply.

Comment: @Vadim I agree. However the basic kinematic equations for constant acceleration like $v^2-u^2=2as $ used here are derived frame dependent right? Unlike the net force.

Answer (score 1):

(Note here I am discussing the flaw with your 1st method. The second method is according to me the most effective)

I think the problem with the 1st case is that it assumes that both the trains decelerate for the entire duration of the time till **both** stop.

However this is not so. Lets say train A stops first and train B is still moving. Then for this remaining time interval in the frame of train B the net deceleration is just a$_b $ and not a$_a$ +a$_b $.

That was an amazing question that rattled my head. Kudos!
(I hope I am not wrong.Feel free to point out any mistakes)

Comment: You don't need to use the stopping times to solve this problem. You do have to assume constant acceleration for each.

Comment: @BillN But if we try to derive it as in the method 1 of op's question then we would require the stopping times right?

Comment: Yes, method 1 does assume the times are the same. Your answer wasn't clear you were talking specifically about that method.

Comment: @BillN I am really sorry for that. I have edited it now. Hope that would make it more clear

Comment: @VamsiKrishna thanks .btw I thought the trains won't stop .they will have same velocity in the same direction .so from a train's frame it'll look like the other train stopped.But correct me if I'm wrong you assumed the trains will stop for real and once it stops it'll not go backwards and then the train will have no acceleration?EDIT:then why does the simulation work for my 1st approach but not the 2nd one?

Comment: @Tekton_infernus Yes when the trains stop I am assuming they won't accelerate backwards again (as in most similar questions I have seen). About your simulation, I can't say for sure but maybe you have taken that the trains accelerate backwards too after stopping? Because in that case the 1st method is perfect, but in the second case $v^2/2a $ calculates distance moved till the trains stop and doesn't consider the further backward displacement

Comment: @VamsiKrishna yeah I thought they will accelerate backwards after stopping (by stopping I assumed , from a train's frame of reference they will stop)

Comment: @Tekton_infernus So that is the problem with the 2nd case in the simulator